# How to add configuration options to devextreme autocomplete component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme

How to add Configuration options to devextreme autocomplete component
Presently the code is

```
<dx-autocomplete [dataSource]='users' 
                 [searchExpr]='["DisplayName","Email"]'   
                 [displayExpr]='["DisplayName","Email"]'}'> 
</dx-autocomplete>
```

The component shows up but, when I type to search a text, options are populating as `[Object Object]` and not options text

```
datasource = [{"DisplayName":"Sa","Email":"sa.gmail.com"}]
```

And search should be possible by both `'Email'` and `'DisplayName'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by using item template and `valueExpr` option. I've prepared [a planker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6l4NIYBisW6Qc3LdGRns?p=preview) that demonstrate this technique.

Comment: Awesome.... perfect fit..... thanks Dmitry Levkovsk. You made my day :)